# Golf score array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, sum

I need help on approaching this problem for my CHS Intro to programming class... The problem states:

Writer a program that asks a user how many rounds of golf they played. Using an array, have the user enter what their scores were for each round of golf they played. Sum the users score and display the total to the user.

What I am confused on is the Array part of the problem... Would it be correct for the user input to be the array size? If so how can I code it so that the user is able to input the arrays size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no. you'd want an array that's 9- or 18-slots big, e.g. a 9- or 18-round of golf. Each slot gets the score for that particular hole, then you sum up the values to get the total score.

Comment: Yes but it says "rounds" of golf.. I thought that meant the total score after all of the holes were played. I think if it were that the problem would have stated how many holes of golf they played

Comment: well, if it's "rounds", e.g. entire games, then you ask how many rounds they played, make an array that big, and fill in the per-round scores. either way, you make an array of scores and then sum them up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
// TODO: Ask how many rounds
...
int total = 0;
int[] scores = new int[numberOfRounds];
for (int round = 0; round < numberOfRounds; round++) {
    // TODO: Ask for score
    scores[round] = score;
    total += score;
}
```

I'm not sure of the purpose of putting the scores in an array, but if that's what's asked for, I guess you have to!

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! I was unaware that that was possible I'll see if it works... Thanks!

Comment: in the for loop would I have to put .length after numberOfRounds or would it work without it

Comment: numberOfRounds is the same as scores.length

Comment: It runs but does not ask for anything after i enter one round..

Comment: Im sorry Im not sure how to neatly add my code into these comments